# Unhandled exception. Access violation

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, access-violation

I was writing some C++ code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int *c = NULL;
    *c = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = *c;
}
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    cout << "a, b: ";
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    swap(&a, &b);
    cout << a << b;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

But when compiled, it said: "Unhandled exception...access violation reading... ". What is wrong with my code?

Comment: hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! While this really isn't bad, it's always recommendable to properly *indent* your code. I'll do this for you in a second. It makes the code much easier to read and makes it easier for you to find structural mistakes.

Comment: The compiler doesn't care about things like indentation and spaces, but people do. Indenting your code makes it more easy for people ro read and understand and follow along with your code.

Comment: Think about what this means: `*c = *a;`

Comment: Your English is not so bad, except you misspelled English :)

Comment: Also, your code can't be [tag:c++11] and [tag:c++14] at the same time. Settle for one – or none, since this works with all versions of C++

Comment: In swap function 'c' is pointing to NULL. When you try to write there (*c = ...) you get access violation.

Comment: You should not try to learn C++ by trial and error, that tends to go poorly.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot dereference a `NULL` pointer as your `swap` method currently does. Luckily, you don't really need `c` as a pointer - you just need an `int` to store the temporary value:

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int c = *a; /* Here */
    *a = *b;
    *b = c;
}
```